# Why do we say "study window" not "study's window"?

Tags: possessives, attributive-nouns

Do you know why we say **study window** not **study's window** although we mean the window which belongs to study(room)?

Comment: Descriptive genitives are not a very productive category. For instance we have _a ship's doctor_, but not *_a school's doctor_ (instead a plain-case nominal is used, _a school doctor)_. Likewise, we have _fisherman's cottages_, but not *_country's cottages_ (instead we again have plain-case _country cottages_).

Comment: @BillJ OK, I want to know the reason. Why don't we put **s** in _study window_ or in your examples? Kitchen sink refer to the usage of sink not the possession(e.g dining table means the table used for dining and it doesn't show the possession. This table can be in shopping store for sale) but study window shows the possession. Can we say the **window of study**?

Comment: @user213464: No. I'd say kitchen is *exactly the same*. It's very common for non-native speakers to assume the Saxon Genitive always reflects "possession" in the sense of "ownership". It doesn't - it just reflects *some kind of relationship*. That's why I voted to migrate this question to ELL (we got a *lot* of questions about this specific point there).

Comment: I don't see how "kitchen sink" is different... look at "bedroom door". Do you agree that is the same as "study window"? If so, certainly you can think of it as "the door to my bedroom" much as you can think of "kitchen sink" as "the sink in my kitchen". The door (or window) doesn't **belong** to the bedroom/study... it's associated with it, just as the sink is associated with the kitchen.

Comment: zkf, you assume incorrectly that study window indicates possession. It doesn't. And that's why you're having difficulty comprehending all the answers @BillJ, FumbleFingers and Catija have given you. Does this help? Change your assumptions and the answers will make sense.

Comment: @Catija, thanks for your explanation. Just one question has remaind. Can we say **the window of study**?

Answer (score -1):

The noun *study* here is used as an adjective describing the window. *study's window*, on the other hand, conveys the idea of possession or ownership. It's like saying that the study went to the market, bought and now owns the window. Well, that's kind of silly, isn't it?

We don't say *a computer's mouse*. We say *a computer mouse* because we use the noun *computer* as an adjective to describe the kind of mouse we're dealing with. Again, we use an apostrophe plus s when we are talking about something that belongs to or is literally owned by somebody or something. No apostrophe s means description, just like *red* in *red car* describes the color of the car. That's really all there is to it at the end of the day.